# How the UIView will get release? Explain

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nsarray, automatic-ref-counting

In ARC, I want to release the custom view added to parent view and array.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIScrollView* panelScroll;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *medsSectionViews;
```

Above are the two properties in which a customview object is added as below:

```
CustomView* newView;
newView = [[CustomView alloc] init];
[panelScroll addSubview:newView];
[self.medsSectionViews addObject:newView];
newView = nil;
```

Its not releasing the object. What is the problem? How can I achieve it? Please mention the reference count at required points.

Comment: newView is not being released because -addSubview: and the array retain it.

Comment: The view is owned by two objects. It cannot be released until those two objects (array, and superview) stop using it. By the way, your code should not use `retain`. It should use `strong`.

Answer (score 1):

```
CustomView *newView = [[CustomView alloc] init]; // 1 owner (the newView local variable)
[panelScroll addSubview:newView];  // 2 owners (local variable, the superview panelScroll)
[self.medsSectionViews addObject:newView]; // 3 owners (local variable, superview, array medsSectionViews)
newView = nil;  // 2 owners (superview, array)
```

now

```
[array removeAllObjects]; // 1 owner (superview)
[newView removeFromSuperview]; // 0 owners
// view gets deallocated because it has no owners
```

Answer (score 0):

Some method will retain object:

In your code:
1. addSubview:
2. addObject:

retain your view;

so your just need:
[array removeAllObjects]; 
[newView removeFromSuperview];

and why newView = nil can't release view ?
Because In ARC it's use Reference counting to management object life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Your newView variable appears to be a local variable. As soon as that goes out of scope it will release it's strong reference to your view. Thus you don't really have to set it to nil.

You have 2 other strong references:

1. Arrays maintain strong references to their contents.
2. When you add a view to a superview, the superview holds a strong reference.

If you want it released, you need to both remove it from the array and remove it from it's superview. Note that it will then be deallocated.